# In which days of week, one can cut neem tree?

Tags: scripture

If one bound to cut a neem tree then in which day one should do that?

Does one need to do puja before that according to scriptures?

Comment: Prof asking for cutting tree? why Prof?? Keep it don't try to cut it. Please check with your local forest Departments and enquire neem is a banned tree or not.